# Streaming Video From Android

Tags: android, camera, video-streaming, rtp

I'm trying to stream video from the Android phone, which should be watched in an mediaplayer.
I've been looking at http://www.mattakis.com/blog/kisg/20090708/broadcasting-video-with-android-without-writing-to-the-file-system which seems to be a dead end since it send the raw file data, and not a streamable format.

Then I tried using some code from SipDroid, more specific; parts of VideoCamera.java, RtpPacket.java and RtpSocket.java, which gives a stream on UDP, however these is not playable in i.e. mplayer(can't detect the codec). Wireshark tells that it is a UDP packet and not a RTP packet so something might be missing?

I'm kind'a stuck, have you any suggestions how to get past this bump?

Comment: Did you get any solution on this problem ?

Comment: What URI are you trying to stream from? The media player will only be able to stream from files using certain protocols

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the packet in Wireshark and select the **decode as** option. Then select **rtp**. Now you can see RTP packets in Wireshark.

Answer (score -8):

I think that you can find the solution from the following code snippet:

```
package com.Videoplaying;

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.net.Uri;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.widget.MediaController;  
import android.widget.VideoView; 

public class Video extends Activity {  
private MediaController mc;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */  
  @Override  
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  setContentView(R.layout.main);  
  VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);  
  String LINK = "http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp";  
  mc = new MediaController(this);  
  mc.setMediaPlayer(vd);  
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(LINK);  
  vd.setMediaController(mc);  
  vd.setVideoURI(uri);  
  vd.requestFocus();  
  vd.start();  
 }  
}
```

Comment: Not a solution. The issue is "stream video FROM the Android phone", not TO the Android phone.