# Android: Send .wav to SIP-Phone via RTP (G.711 PCMU) very noisy, crackling sound based on SipDroid/MjSIP

Tags: java, android, audio, rtp, mjsip

I want to transmit(send-only) a .wav file from my android to a softphone (x-lite) so that the called person on x-lite can hear the sound of the .wav file.

The scenario is as follows:
Android and x-lite are both in the same WLAN and both connected to FreeSwitch. I can call x-lite from the android phone. If the call is accepted on the x-lite the android sends the .wav file and I can see in wireshark that RTP pakets (G.711 PCMU) are send from the phone to x-lite. I can hear some sound but not the one I would expect. Instead its crackling, noisy and some beeps.

So is there a problem in the SDP I send to the x-lite?

```
v=0
o=sip:1002@192.168.2.110 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.2.100
s=MySession
c=IN IP4 192.168.2.110
t=0 0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
```

Or is the problem the way I send the .wav?

```
DatagramSocket socket = null;
RtpStreamSender sender = null;
int port =8000;
int payload_type = 0;
int frameSize = 64;
int frameRate =32; 
socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
FileInputStream audioInput = new FileInputStream(f); //f is the .wav
sender = new RtpStreamSender(audioInput, true, payload_type, frameRate, frameSize, remoteAddress, remotePort);
sender.setSyncAdj(2);
sender.start();
```

If I follow UDP Stream in Wireshark the beginning looks like this:

> ........M...RIFF....WAVEfmt
>   ........D...........data0...............................M..........................................................................>M..........................................................................]M..........................................................................|M.....................
>   ....................... ..... .......................M...........
>   .........................
>   .....................................M...........................................................
>   ...............M...............................................
>   .......+...5...8...........M...6...+.'...-...(.....#...-...+...
>   ...........................
>   ...........M......................................................................
>   ...6M......... ...
>   ............................................................UM...........-...1...0...,...)...'...0...?...=.#.'.$.
>   .!....................tM.............................$.......................
>   .....&.......... ....M...........................
>   ...................................,...........M...=...I...W...J.../.....................#...<...T...Z...B.................M.....#...5...5...................*..."...
>   .....
>   .......5.W.L...N...........M...C...8.m.'.R...>...O...p...~...e...I...3...*.............................M...................................................
>   .......................M...
>   ...5...R...L...3.../...B...Z...b...`...X...B...!.........{............MM.........$...2...(........................................................lM...............................-.!.R.J.].s.Z.t.U.c.b.`.q.v.....y...........M...h...V...Y...c...l.f.E.*.............................(...E...X...........M...J...5.H.7.5.^...~...j.................(.=.h.........F.....Q...(.........M.....E.X...{...L.2...............:.......Q.......v...........
>   .............M.................0...S...K...7.+.B.....................&...O...]...........M...r.B.......w...8.Q...?...A...>...................).../.

So I guess its not empty. After the beginning of the signal, some signal is send from the x-lite to the android and then again some pakets from the android to x-lite... and so on

Can anyone give me a hint why I can't hear the sound?

(Other solutions are also welcome)
Edit:

this is the implementation of RTPStramSender from MjSip: http://pastebin.com/xU4EdEex

Edit 2:
I changed the SDP like in the RFC to:

```
     m=audio 54874 RTP/AVP 96 97 0 8
     a=rtpmap:96 PCMU-WB/16000
     a=rtpmap:97 PCMA-WB/16000
     a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
     a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
```

But nothing hapened. I changed framesize and framerate but the crackling only gets faster or slower

Edit 3:
the implementation of RtpPacket:
http://pastebin.com/tDLr5CYF

Comment: I unfortunately have only experience with video and RTP, but I guess you might have to packetize the audio similar as you would do with image data. Or is that what the RtpStreamSender does?

Comment: I added the source of RTPStreamSender. Could you give me a hint how to packetize the audio?

Comment: This RFC should help: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5391.

Comment: Changing SDP didn't change anything.

Comment: I still have the packetization under suspicion. The RTPStreamSender uses a class "RtpPacket", which I guess does the packetization - do you have code for that one, too? Maybe, there is a parameter to be set or something ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the RtpPacket class above.

Comment: OK I guess you are right. I made some minor changes on the RtpPacket class like sipdroid does. The crackling is gone. But now it sounds like two robots speaking into a tin bucket. The original .wav sound is two persons talking slow to each other. I can hear two different voices but I can't hear what they where talking. Any hints?

Comment: No, sorry. I have no experience with sound.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I guess I found a problem in another class which does the G.711 coding. Perhaps this causes the ugly sound

Comment: Changing G.711 like in sipdroid doesn't help: http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/media/G711.java?r=386

Comment: @Fildor If you post any answer, you will get the bonty for your help and effort :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is the packetizing.

This RFC tells you how it is suppoed to be done:
[RFC 5391](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5391)

Turned out that this helped a little bit, but not all the way. If someone can help and it works, please accept his answer rather than mine.